# How to change title of a Tab in TabActivity

Tags: android, title, tabactivity

I have TabActivity **with tabs on bottom** which is composed of several different activities like this:

```
public class HomeScreen extends TabActivity {
private TabHost mTabHost;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    try{
    setContentView(R.layout.hometabs);


    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    mTabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
    String strName;
    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    strName=Central.Res.getString(R.string.tab_Books);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BookList.class);
    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(strName).setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_database))
                  .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);


    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    strName=Central.Res.getString(R.string.tab_Questions);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, QuestionsList.class);
    intent.putExtra("NoteType",  UserDataSQLHelper.NOTE_TYPE_QUEST );
    spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(strName).setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_dialog))
                  .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);
```

My problem is that I have the same window title for every tab. This window title is set to application name.

I need to be able to change this title to the name of the tab.

I am trying to do it by calling setTitle("MyTitle"); in onCreate() of corresponding activity and by overriding TabActivity onChildTitleChanged:

```
        public void onChildTitleChanged(Activity childActivity, CharSequence title)
        {
             View tabView = mTabHost.getCurrentTabView();
             int idTitle = android.R.id.title;
             TextView tvTitle = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(idTitle);
             tvTitle.setText(title);
        }
```

But the result I get isn't what I need - it sets text to tab under the tab icon.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with following code,

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {                
                Log.i("Tab id", ""+tabId);
                setTitle(tabId);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, already tried that. Does the same - changes text under tab icon.

Comment: Thanks for that! It works. The only thing is that first opened tab still gets a wrong title, user has to switch tabs to reset it.

Comment: at the time of loading tabs set the title with firs tab content. If it is worked well then accept this answer, for doing this others can make use of this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`setIndicator (CharSequence label, Drawable icon)`.
Use this function and the label will be shown as a title.